# Why list-ref works with pair

Tags: list, scheme, racket

In the following code:

```
(define l (cons 1 2))
l
(list? l)
(pair? l)
(list-ref l 0)  ; works;
(list-ref l 1)  ; DOES NOT WORK;
```

Output:

```
'(1 . 2)
#f
#t
1
Error: list-ref: index reaches a non-pair
  index: 1
  in: '(1 . 2)
```

Why (list-ref l 0) works if l is not a list. Otherwise, why (list-ref l 1) does not work. This behavior seems to be inconsistent and confusion creating.

The functions `car` and `cdr` also work, returning 1 and 2, respectively. Why should `cdr` work if this is not a list. One would expect `car` to return `1.2` and not just 1.

Comment: As a note: you seem to ask a fair number of questions that could be solved by solved by just reading the documentation. Racket’s documentation is very good. At the risk of telling you to RTFM, please… read the documentation before asking a question.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify this aspect of lists and pairs but I take your point well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-ref%29%29):

> The `lst` argument need not actually be a list; `lst` must merely start with a chain of at least `(add1 pos)` pairs.

This means the `lst` argument is allowed to be an improper list as long as the index is smaller than the index of the first pair whose `cdr` is a non-pair.

Answer (score 4):

A list is simply a lot of pairs linked together terminating in an empty list. For example, `(list 1 2 3)` is equivalent to `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))`.

There's no reason to loop through the entire list to check if `l` is a list, so as long as it looks like a list, scheme doesn't care if it terminates in an empty list. `list-ref` is basically defined as so:

```
(define (list-ref lyst index)
    (cond ((= index 0) (car index))
          (else (list-ref (cdr lyst) (- index 1)))))
```

So of course it will encounter an error when it tries to run `(car 2)`

As for the other question, `car` and `cdr` simply return the first element in a pair and the second element in a pair respectively.